# Have there already been sucessful attempts at using induction proof methods for the rationals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

I developed a proof method which builds on natural induction for propositions regarding closed intervals of $\mathbb{Q}$. The description takes very little effort and it boils down to the use of two inductions, I've just sent it to Acta Mathematica and I'd like to know if there have already been other methods that allow for rational induction.
I already knew about transfinite induction before doing this, the main appeal of the paper is in the construction itself.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a "rational induction"?

Comment: Well, you could take the proposition $2^{n} \leq n! $ for $n\geq4$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and then by means of this rational induction we could generalize it for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $q\geq4$

Comment: I didn't mean an example of a statement you could prove by rational induction, I meant an example of an actual proof by rational induction. I want to see what you concretely mean by that via an example.

Comment: Ok, the process is kind of long but I'll go through the general motions as described in the paper.

Comment: Since we know that every rational in an interval $[a,b]$, $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$ can be expressed as $r=\frac{x|b-a|}{n+x} + a$ where $n,x\in \mathbb{N}$ we can picture the rational elements of the interval as $p\in \{a\} \cup R_{k}$, where $R_{k}=\bigcup\limits_{x=1}^{k} (A_i=\{r=\frac{x|b-a|}{n+x} +a\})$, $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$ we can then prove the proposition to be true all rationals in the interval by proving the proposition for $a$, then doing one induction over n in the set $A_{1}$ and taking it as the base case for induction over $k$.

Comment: It is painstakingly long though

Comment: The rationals are countable, so if you order a subset of the rationals in a certain way, you can do induction on them as well. For instance, in your case, you can do "induction" on all rationals in $[0,1]$ by considering the sequence $x_n$ defined by $0, 1, 1/2, 1/3, 2/3, 1/4, 3/4, 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1/6, ...$ and saying that if a result is true for $x_k$ for all $k < n$ then it must be true for $x_n$. The reformulation may be interesting in a particular example (that's why I was asking for a concrete example, not an explanation of the technique).

Comment: My bad, sorry. I just developed the method, I'm wary of trying to apply it because induction type stuff is consistently long, this thing asks for 2 separate inductions at the very least, it might take up to 4 or 5 consecutive inductive proofs. My hands hurt just thinking about it.

Comment: Is the construction paper worthy at least? The actual math is only half a page in length.

Comment: One could do an induction on the rationals by doing an induction on the denominator and, within that, an induction on the numerator (or the other way around). Acta Math has very very very high standards for publication. If you don't have a track record of solid publications, the chances are you're fooling yourself as to the value of what you've done.

Comment: It's very likely that's the case, I'd still throught it'd be nice to give it a try since I didn't find any papers using similar methods

Comment: Based on your sketch it sounds like you're just talking about a particular version of double induction, is that right?

Comment: yup, pretty much